# PnPutil commands to uninstall the display adapter driver does not work

Tags: windows, powershell, driver

I am currently trying to uninstall display adapter driver in power shell.
I can simply go to device manager to find display adapter and uninstall the driver and then install the new driver. But I want to write an automated script to make it easy.

I tried to use "pnputil.exe -f -d oem##.inf" in power shell  to uninstall the display adapter driver.

But it did not work and gave me something like that

"Deleting the driver package failed: One or more devices are presently installed using the specified INF"

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem and make pnputil work?

Comment: You might have to unload the driver first with devcon.

Comment: I agree with myself, lol.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a PowerShell question really, as it's a window util.

from running `pnputil /?`

```
/delete-driver <oem#.inf> [/force]
Delete driver package from the driver store.
/force - delete driver package even when it is in use by devices.
```

so running `pnputil.exe /delete-driver oem##.inf /force` should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that one still get me same message.

Comment: @John are you sure you're running it fully elevated?

Comment: powershell as admin and still same message in windows 10 pro

Answer (score 0):

Example removing a device using the driver first on the commandline with devon.  Devon comes with the Window SDK.  [Windows SDK - Windows app development _ Microsoft Developer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/)  The pnputil command should work after that.

```
devcon remove "HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_1013&DEV_4206&SUBSYS_106B0600"
```